# pod network add-on flannel : diff between 'kubernetes official doc url' and 'github url' for kube-flannel.yml

Tags: github, kubernetes, flannel

I'm installing pod network addon flannel to my cluster.

On the official kubernetes doc, the url to install flannel add-on is

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/62e44c867a2846fefb68bd5f178daf4da3095ccb/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

and on the github repository wiki, the url is

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

So what is the diff ? Which url should I apply ?

thank you for some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same document, but potentially different versions.
You can view the [version history](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/commits/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml), and observe that `62e44c867a28` is (as of this answer) the second-most-recent version.

That particular change is described at https://github.com/coreos/flannel/pull/1162 - basically updating definitions from a beta format to a newer format that is less likely to change going forward.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm not familiar yet with github so I didn't realize. So `62e44c867a2846fefb68bd5f178daf4da3095ccb` was commited on Feb 15, 2019  and `d893bcbfe6b04791054aea6c7569dea4080cc289`  on Jul 18, 2019 . How can I update my cluster ? by applying the last url or should I remove the second-most-recent version with `kubectl delete -f`

Comment: There is still opened issue on github [Provide more concrete guidance on upgrading flannel on Kubernetes](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/706)